# Getting an error randomly : cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: jqgrid

I get an error randomly from the grid: `cannot read property 'split' of undefined` in `jqGrid.js` file. Here is the screenshot of the error line:

[image]

What could be the reason for this?

Note: Grid keeps on refreshing itself in few seconds and I have tried to maintain the expanded state of grid when it is set to collapsed by default.

Version used: `4.6.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't posted the demo with the test data, which can be used to reproduce the problem. Thus I have to guess to describe the reason of the problem.

It's small problem in the *implementation* of old jqGrid 4.6. It sets `onClick` attribute on expand/collapse icon span, which look like

```js
onclick="jQuery('#list').jqGrid('groupingToggle','listghead_1_1');return false;"
```

I suppose the data, which you use, generates some wrong parameter for `groupingToggle`. Another possible reason would be just calling `groupingToggle` directly from your code with wrong parameter. You should examine your code for direct calls of `groupingToggle` and the parameters used.

In any way the problem should be fixed in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), the fork of jqGrid which I develop. It extends the attributes of `<tr>` used as grouping header with additional attribute `data-jqgrouplevel`. Free jqGrid uses the attribute instead of usage `.split("_")`. Thus it can't produce any errors like you describes.

I mention you already before about [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). I understand that there are situations where one can't upgrade to new version not so easy. Nevertheless you should understand that old version 4.6 is dad. No bugs will be fixed in the version. Thus you have to migrate wither to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) or to [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or to support your own fork based on jqGrid 4.6 or just to migrate to some alternative product. No other fixes will be made more in old jqGrid 4.6.

Comment: Okay. I am almost done with the migration to `free jqgrid`. I have done the necessary work! However, I am not sure about the `css`. When I use new `css` it makes some weird changes into my grid. Like [here after new css](http://oi63.tinypic.com/n5g678.jpg) pager gets a full length

Comment: @SuhailGupta: You should provide **the demo** which can be used to analyse the results. I suppose you have some outer dives with float attributes and you need just include some additional CSS property like `clear: both`, but I can only guess if I have not working demo.